# Kinematics problem involving two balls

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

I'm having trouble with a kinematics problem and was hoping someone could help me out. The problem goes like this:

> "A ball is dropped from rest from a point P on a tree branch 5 m above the ground. At the same time, another ball is thrown with initial speed v0 from a point 1 m above the ground and 4 m away from the first ball. In what direction should the second ball be thrown to hit the first ball? Neglect air resistance."

I attempted to solve the problem by using the kinematic equations for motion in two dimensions. For the first ball, I found its position as a function of time to be y1 = 5 - (1/2)gt^2, where g is the acceleration due to gravity. For the second ball, I assumed it would travel in a straight line towards the point where the two balls meet, which we can call point Q. I then used the distance formula to relate the position of the second ball at time t to the position of point Q, and tried to solve for the direction in which the second ball should be thrown.

However, I'm stuck at this point and don't know how to proceed. I would really appreciate any help or insights anyone could offer.

Comment: How would the ball travel following a straight line? Does that mean the ball has no acceleration?

Comment: The second ball moves with constant velocity horizontalyl, but falls vertically in the same manner as the other ball. Time for collision is assumed to be equal if measured by a common clock.

Comment: You might want to look into the [monkey and hunter problem.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_and_hunter)